# Should I change the port from 3000 on an Express app / Nginx for security

Tags: express, nginx, async-await, nginx-config

Should I change the port from 3000 on an Express app and Nginx for security, or doesn't matter? I have it set to get the port number from aws parameter store, would this be more secure than storing it as an environmental variable on the server? If I should change the port what is a good number to change it to?

```
const param = require('./param');
param.getSecret('po').then((port) => {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Express server running on: " + port)
  })
});
```

param.js

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({ region: "us-east-1" });
// const ssm = require('./aws-client');

const getSecret = async (ss) => {
  console.log(`Getting secret for ${ss}`);
  const params = {
    Name: ss, 
    WithDecryption: true
  };

  const result = await ssm.getParameter(params).promise();
  return result.Parameter.Value;
};

module.exports = { getSecret };
```

session

```
param.getSecret('ss').then((secret) => {
  app.use(session({
    proxy: true,
    secret: secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }

  }))
  console.log("SECRET: " + secret)
});
```

Comment: i mean youre using a proxy anyways to send your app to the webserver, i dont see any issue with using port 3000

Comment: If you're already operating behind nginx and thus not open to the general internet in any way, it's not clear to me why changing the port you are running on would make any security difference.

Comment: @Jfriend00 Thanks, what about the express 'session secret', should I get that from parameter store? Added code above

Comment: I'm not an AWS expert, but it seems you might want to use the secrets manager for the session secret.  See [this article](https://medium.com/awesome-cloud/aws-difference-between-secrets-manager-and-parameter-store-systems-manager-f02686604eae) for a discussion about secrets manager vs parameter store.